# Batch adding of SEGY files to QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, import

I am working with a set of legacy Archaeology GPR data that contains a massive batch of `.segy` files. Each file has multiple layers forcing me to "Select Vector Layers" to add. Is there a way of bypassing this and batch adding all files to QGIS? I am just starting to learn Python and QGIS.

[image: Photo of what is coming up every time]

Comment: Could you share a sample data or link? I have some segy files but QGIS doesn't recognize them.

Comment: The Data is hosted as https://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archives/view/romancities_ahrc_2019/downloads.cfm. 
SEG-Y Files seem to have been deprecated from GDAL as of the last update, I have to run the LTS 3.16 to use the files.